# Oracle Java 8 doesn't support Cipher Suite TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384

Tags: java, java-8, ibm-mq

How to enable TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 in java 1.8.0_51?

My environment

```
Windows Server 2016
java version 1.8.0_51
```

I need to upgrade the MQ channel and cipher suite from C2 to C6 in several projects in the same server. I have upgrade the MQ jars and MQ connection configurations in those projects.
 
**Same Error message** in log from different projects: Cannot support TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 with currently installed providers.

**What I have done after checking the log:**
**Step 1:** Download Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 8 from https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html
**Step 2:** Unzip jce_policy-8.zip and replace existing local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_51\lib\security with the new ones
**Step 3:** Check supported cipher suites in cmd using following commands:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_51\bin>jjs
jjs> print(java.util.Arrays.toString(javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault().getSupportedCipherSuites()).replaceAll(",","\n"))
```

**The result I expect**

```
[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
 TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
 TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
 TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
... ]
```

**However**, all cipher suites name starts with "TLS_ECDH" are not showed up in the result, including the one I configured in my projects TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384.
Then I notice that even before upgrading the JCE jars, TLS_ECDH* are not supported.

I think it might related to the security.provider setting in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_51\lib\security\java.security. But I don't know what I need to change.
Here is my current security.provider setting:

```
security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun
security.provider.2=sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
security.provider.3=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider
security.provider.4=com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE
security.provider.5=sun.security.jgss.SunProvider
security.provider.6=com.sun.security.sasl.Provider
security.provider.7=org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI
security.provider.8=sun.security.smartcardio.SunPCSC
security.provider.9=sun.security.mscapi.SunMSCAPI
```

Comment: Add my current security.provider setting in the question desc.

Comment: Update java? The latest java 8 build 222

Comment: Hi Minn, I am not allowed to update java version for now.

Comment: Then you risk major security vulnerabilities, such as broken SNI.

Comment: Thank you Minn. From the research I have done, a few "TLS_ECDH..." cipher suites should be enabled by default. The issue is that I don't have any of them.

Comment: If you can't upgrade Java or install new providers you can't solve this problem, because those are the solutions.

Comment: Is this with IBM MQ?  Have you checked your java.security file to make sure that `crypto.policy=unlimited` is not commented out?  From what I understand java 8 build 151 started to include the policy files but you had to set the above setting to have them enabled, at build 162 they are include and enabled by default.

Comment: @JoshMc I don't have `crypto.policy=unlimited` at all, thus I added it in java.security. However it doesn't work.

Comment: Is this IBM MQ?

Comment: @user207421 Do you mean upgrade Java is the only solution of installing new providers?

Comment: @JoshMc Yes, IBM MQ.

Comment: Did you install this with the Oracle installer? Can you re-install, or retry elsewhere (like a test VM)? My saved copy (from 2015!) of _Oracle JDK_ (which should be the same as JRE) 8u51 Windows 32bit has provider 3 = `sun.security.ec.SunEC` and the rest +1 compared to yours, as do all other 7 and 8 versions I have, plus 9-12 (except now in conf/security). PS @JoshMC: 151 and 152 added the policy, **161** and up enabled it by default.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Adding provider `sun.security.ec.SunEC` solves the issue! Thank you very much!

Comment: No, I meant what I said. Your only solutions are to upgrade Java *or* install another provider, such as BC.

Comment: @user207421 but as you can set if you read the comments above the `security.provider.3` was just wrong in the `java.security` file.